# sql - How to get the average of datediff in days between two dates of a single column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I figured this would be easy, but the only way I can get this figured out is a temp table.  Basically I have 1 column called `myDate' which is a  datetime column And what I want to know is the average difference in days for all these rows.

So Basically the results are this

`1/1/2014`
`1/14/2014`
`1/20/2014`

so basically i want to know the average is 9.5 days.  1/1 - 1/14 is 13 days and 14/20 is 6 days, so 19 / 2 is 9.5

my basic query is `select myDate from myTable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The average is the maximum minus the minimum divided by one less than the number of days.  So, you can get it as:

```
select datediff(day, min(myDate), max(myDate)) / cast(count(*) - 1 as float)
from temp;
```

If you wanted to be real careful, you might prevent the potential divide-by-zero error:

```
select (case when count(*) > 1
             then datediff(day, min(myDate), max(myDate)) / cast(count(*) - 1 as float)
             else 0
        end)
from temp;
```

Comment: I would prefer not to do this with a temp table at all

Comment: Does this account for all dates in the select?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a temp table probably, but I'm not convinced the above method is true for all circumstances. Your requirement is to compare the date of one row to the date of the next row, but there is no indication that the 'next row date' is always greater than the previous date. If a pair of dates produce a negative result from datediff() the duration between those dates ignores the sign i.e. is the absolute value. e.g. if we calculate `datediff(day,2014-01-02,2013-01-03)` the result is -364, but in truth the duration is 364 because we should have flipped the date sequence in the datediff() function.

```
|     MYDATE |    NXTDATE | RAWDIFF | DAYDIFF |
|------------|------------|---------|---------|
| 2013-01-01 | 2014-01-02 |     366 |     366 |
| 2014-01-02 | 2013-01-03 |    -364 |     364 |
| 2013-01-03 | 2014-01-27 |     389 |     389 |
| 2014-01-27 | 2013-01-28 |    -364 |     364 |
| 2013-01-28 | 2014-01-29 |     366 |     366 |
| 2014-01-29 | 2014-06-30 |     152 |     152 |
| 2014-06-30 |     (null) |  (null) |  (null) |
```

So, with dates possibly going backward and forward, measuring the average duration by a total span could be misleading.

```
|     MIN_DT |     MAX_DT | MAX_MIN_SPAN | SPAN_AVG | SUM_DAYDIFFS | COUNT | TRUE_AVG |
|------------|------------|--------------|----------|--------------|-------|----------|
| 2013-01-01 | 2014-06-30 |          545 | 90.83333 |         2001 |     6 |    333.5 |
```

queries used for this:

```
SELECT
      MIN(mydate)                                                       min_dt
    , MAX(mydate)                                                       max_dt
    , DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(mydate), MAX(mydate))                           max_min_span
    , DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(mydate), MAX(mydate)) / (COUNT(daydiff) * 1.0)  span_avg

    , SUM(daydiff)                                                      sum_daydiffs
    , COUNT(daydiff)                                                    count_daydiffs
    , SUM(daydiff) / (COUNT(daydiff) * 1.0)                             true_avg
FROM (
            SELECT
                  mydate
                , ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, mydate, LEAD(mydate) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) )) AS daydiff
            FROM mytable
      ) sq
;

SELECT
        mydate
      , lead(mydate) over(order by (select 1)) nxtdate
      , DATEDIFF(DAY, mydate, LEAD(mydate) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) )      AS rawdiff
      , ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, mydate, LEAD(mydate) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) )) AS daydiff
FROM mytable
;
```

see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a7cdc/4